# Realmを使ってToDoをつくる: Expected member name or constructor call after type name

Tags: swift, realm

[【初心者向け】徹底詳解！cocoapod + RealmでToDoアプリを作るチュートリアル (全4回) - Qiita](https://qiita.com/g08m11/items/8d4f7e82e89195ff301c)

上記ページのチュートリアルに従ってToDoをつくっていたのですが、下記コードの`return realm.objects(ToDo)`という箇所で、

```
Expected member name or constructor call after type name
```

というエラーが表示されてしまいます。

他のエラーは解消できたのですが、この箇所だけどうやってもエラーが消せませんでした。
どうすれば解消できるのか教えていただけますでしょうか。

**ソースコード**

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class ViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet var todoNameText: UITextField!

  @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

  var toDoItems:Results<ToDo>?{
    do{
      let realm = try Realm()
      return realm.objects(ToDo)
    }catch{
      print("エラー")
    }
    return nil
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`Realm.objects(_:)`のパラメータにはクラスオブジェクト（メタタイプ）を渡します。
Swiftの文法ではメタタイプを取得するには`ToDo.self`と`ToDo`の後に`.self`が必要です。